# PHP How to encode(escape) @, for email validation?

Tags: php, escaping

I'm getting this error:

> Error Number: 1064 
>       You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL   server version for the right syntax to use near '@gmail.com' at line 1

Here's the code:

```
$email = $this->input->post('email');

                $checkEmail = $this->crud_model->retrieve_where('employee', 'email', 'email', $email);
```

crud_model:

```
function retrieve_where($table, $table_id, $table_name, $value) {
        $table = $this->db->query('Select * FROM ' . $table . ' Where ' . $table_id . ' = ' . $value);
        $records = array();
        foreach ($table->result() as $row) {
            $records[] = $row->$table_name;
        }
        return $records;
    }
```

Comment: Basically use '' to enclose your values Select * FROM employee Where email = 'b@gmail.com'

Comment: Quote strings: `Select * FROM employee Where email = 'b@gmail.com'` You don't show what your retieve_where() does, but I'm quessing it doesn't use prepared statements, or quote strings correctly

Comment: quotes go where?? $this->crud_model->retrieve_where('employee', 'email', 'email', $email);

Comment: post your crud_model that is building the query

Comment: I posted the crud_model.

Comment: What´s strange here is that the crud_model class evaluates the $email value as an integer to build the sql. Can you try with any value instead of a valid email and post the results?

Comment: NOW in the $this->db->query() put the quotes around the value and mysql_real_escape() it or use PDO prepare etc..

Comment: Don't build SQL by mashing strings together. Use bound arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query that you try to execute is:

> SELECT * FROM Email WHERE Email = email@email.com

Email is in this case a string, and a string needs to be quoted.

```
function retrieve_where($table, $table_id, $table_name, $value) {
    $table = $this->db->query("Select * FROM " . mysql_real_escape_string($table) . " Where " . mysql_real_escape_string($table_id) . " = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($value) ."'");
    $records = array();
    foreach ($table->result() as $row) {
        $records[] = $row->$table_name;
    }
    return $records;
}
```

Dont forget to escape your query with `mysql_real_escape_string()`. It will protect you against injections.

Comment: also .. if this is a generic function, it would not work if the value is a number.

Comment: @lemil77 MSSQL and MySQL are convert it for you. But you should consider another approach to execute your queries.

Comment: @YourCommonSense can you substantiate / explain your comment?